# MongoDB/Mongoose - Aggregation with geoNear & subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I'm using the [node-geoip](https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip) module and performing an aggregation query. The schema against which I am performing the query looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./location.js');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Region',{
    attr1: Number,
    attr2: String,
    attr3: String,
    locations:[mongoose.model('Location').schema]
});
```

and

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location',{
    attr1: Number,
    latlong: { type: [Number], index: '2d' },
});
```

I need to perform a $geoNear operation in an aggregation query, but I'm running into a few problems. First, here is my aggregation method:

```
var region = require('../models/region');

var geo = geoip.lookup(req.ip);

region.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$locations"},
    {$project: {
        attr1 : 1,
        attr2 : 1,
        locations : 1,
        lower : {"$cond" : [{$lt: [ '$locations.attr1', '$attr1']}, 1, 0]}
    }},
     {
      $geoNear: {
         near: { type:"Point", '$locations.latlong': geo.ll },
         maxDistance: 40000,
         distanceField: "dist.calculated"
      }
     },
    { $sort: { 'locations.attr1': -1 } },
    {$match : {lower : 1}},
    { $limit: 1 }
], function(err,f){...});
```

The first problem I'm getting is that apparently geoNear must be in the first stage of the pipeline: `exception: $geoNear is only allowed as the first pipeline stage`. So my question is, can I perform a geoNear search in the subdocuments without unwinding them? If so, how?

The other error message I get is `errmsg: \"exception: 'near' field must be point\"`. What does this mean and what does it imply for my code? I have tried using `near` as:

```
near: { type:"Point", '$locations.latlong': geo.ll },
```

Comment: Did you try to define "near" as a point? For example; 

near: [longitude, latitude],

Comment: Indexes on arrays are multikey. The `$geoNear` should work fine on an array - ordering should be by the closest point in each document. The second error says you're not using `$geoNear` with the right syntax. Check out [`$geoNear`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/), particularly the examples at the bottom.

Comment: @wdberkeley Thanks for the response. When you say 'ordering should be by the closest point in each document', what do you mean? I don't really understand what that means for my code? Does that mean I can move `$geoNear` to the first stage before unwinding `$locations`?

Comment: @wdberkeley Also, how is my syntax wrong? I've seen those examples and have followed their convention. What specifically is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a disclaimer: I am not a Node/Mongoose expert so I am hoping you can translate the general formats to Node/Mongoose.

For the error:

```
 errmsg: "exception: 'near' field must be point"
```

For a '2d' index this cannot be a [GeoJson](http://geojson.org/) point and instead needs to be a "legacy coordinate pair".  e.g.,

```js
{
  "$geoNear": {
    "near": geo.ll,
    "maxDistance": 40000,
    "distanceField": "dist.calculated"
  }
}
```

If you want to use GeoJSON you will need to use a '2dsphere' index.

With that change the $geoNear query will work with the array of points in the query. An example in the shell:

```js
> db.test.createIndex({ "locations": "2d" })
> db.test.insert({ "locations": [ [1, 2], [10, 20] ] });
> db.test.insert({ "locations": [ [100, 100], [180, 180] ] });
> db.test.aggregate([{
  "$geoNear": {
    "near": [10, 10],
    "maxDistance": 40000,
    "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
    num: 1
  }
}]);
{
  "result": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("552aaf7478dd9c25a3472a2a"),
    "locations": [
      [
        1,
        2
      ],
      [
        10,
        20
      ]
    ],
    "dist": {
      "calculated": 10
    }
  }],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Note that you only get a single distance per document (the closest point) which is semantically not the same as doing the unwind and then determining the distance to every point. I cannot be sure if that is important for your use case.